# Splitting data from text file with if statement and StreamReader

Tags: c#

I am trying to use a combobox alongside a load function.

as the code stands: (just loading in the data - 2nd object)

```
private void btnLoadBooks_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] lineOfContents = File.ReadAllLines("BookList.txt");
    foreach (var line in lineOfContents)
    {
        string[] tokens = line.Split(',');
        lbxBooks.Items.Add(tokens[1]);
    }
}
```

Is there a way to use the combobox as a filter eg.

```
if (cbxBookType.SelectedItem == "PB")
{
    sting[] tokens = line.split(',');
    <read line only with "PB"????>
}
else if...
```

would this work or is there an easier way to do it?

Comment: what does _only with "PB"_ mean ?

Comment: @Selman22 so, if the text in the combobox has PB selected, it will only show those in lbxBooks

Comment: Is `PB` a column(f.e. publisher) and you ant to show only the selected column? If so you need some kind of mapping. Or is it a filter and you want to show only the second column but only strings that start with/contain `PB` (for example)?

Comment: @TimSchmelter PB is the start of the line of the .txt file so the file reads PB,A Tale of Two Cities,Charles Dickens - so i need to only search PB, but return A Tale of Two Cities

Comment: @mcclma: then you have to filter by the first element of the array, so: `if(tokens[0] == "PB")`. Or replace `PB` with `cbxBookType.SelectedItem` if you always want to filter by the selected item even if it's not `PB`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean, the lines that contains the `PB` you can do this:

```
 foreach (var line in  File.ReadLines("BookList.txt")
                           .Where(x => x.Contains("PB")))
{
     string[] tokens = line.Split(',');
     lbxBooks.Items.Add(tokens[1]);
}
```

if you want to search the lines based on `SelectedItem` of your `ComboBox` use `.Where(x => x.Contains(cbxBookType.SelectedItem.ToString())` instead.

Comment: Is there a way yo us PB in the background search but have the user see another word EG Physical Book?

Comment: yes,you want some kind of mapping. you can use a dictionary for that

Comment: how would i go about mapping it?

Comment: you can search on google,about how to use dictionary in C#. I have already answered your question, ask another question, if you have more questions

Comment: thank you very much. I used private void cbxBookType_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) - with a if statement.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach which selects the second column if the first column is `PB` which seems to be your actual requirement acc. to a comment to your question:

```
var values = File.ReadLines("BookList.txt")
    .Select(l => l.Split(','))
    .Where(arr => arr[0] == "PB")
    .Select(arr => arr[1]);
lbxBooks.Items.AddRange(values.ToArray());
```